# Set date from modal AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, date, datepicker

I have a modal and a panel in AngularJS. Now what I want to do is to display the date after I select it from the modal, to be displayed in the panel. I have a start date and an end date.

This is the body of my modal, where I am able to select the start date and end date:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <md-input-container flex> <input type="date"
            ng-model="startDateL"> </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex> <input
            type="date" ng-model="endDateL"> </md-input-container>
        <md-button ng-click="setDate()" class="md-primary">Update</md-button>
    </div>
```

This is the body of my panel:

```
  <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="row" ng-init="defaultDate()">
                <div class="col-lg-12" ng-if="stDate && endDate"> 

                    <p>{{ stDate | date : 'longDate' }} - {{
                        endDate | date : 'longDate' }}</p>
                </div> 

         </div>
  </div>
```

This is the JS file:

```
 angular.module('appl').directive('datePickerDirective',function($mdDialog, $rootScope, $filter){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'components/date-picker-select/date-picker-select.html',
        scope: {},

        controller:function($scope){

            $scope.defaultDate = function(){
                console.log("Dateeeeeeeee");
                var date = new Date();
                $scope.startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),1);
                $scope.todaysDate = new Date();
            }

             $scope.footerLinkClicked  = function(){    
                $mdDialog.show({
                    controller : datePickerController,
                    templateUrl : 'components/date-picker-select/date-picker-modal.html',
                    parent : angular.element(document.body),
                    clickOutsideToClose:true
                }).then(function(answer) {
                    console.log("Fff");
                }, function() {
                });    
            }

        },

        controllerAs: 'DatePickerCtrl'

    }

})

function datePickerController($scope, $mdDialog, $rootScope, datePickerFactory, $filter){
    console.log("suntem in date picker sel");
    var date = new Date();
    $scope.startDateL =  new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),1);
    $scope.endDateL = new Date();


    $scope.close = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
        console.log("closing");
    }

    $scope.setDate = function(startDate, endDate) {
        $rootScope.startDate = $scope.startDateL;
        $rootScope.endDate = $scope.endDateL;


        $scope.stDate = $filter('date')($rootScope.startDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');
        $scope.enDate = $filter('date')($rootScope.endDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');

        console.log(stDate);
        console.log(enDate);

        $rootScope.$broadcast('dateWasChosen');
        $mdDialog.hide();

    }

}
```

I tried to display the stDate and endDate after I set them both in the setDate function() but it was not working. Someone having other ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure what a modal is so I can't help directly, but I think you probably need to look more deeply into what scope you're in when you setting values. I am pretty sure a modal would be in its own scope and you're expecting it not to be. Do some debugging, log the scope variable at different levels and find where the data is actually being stored

Comment: In $mdDialog.hide(); add an object with your start and end date values and then check what the answer variable is in your .then of the dialog.show